# How to display JSON file data in HTML ? Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

JSON data contains a collection of questions on which I am trying to display in html. I used `ng-repeat` for looping JSON data like `ng-repeat="q in response"` and trying to print like

{{q.q1}}

{{q.q2}}

{{q.q3}}

Executed in chrome but data are not coming.

questionaire.json

```
{
    "questionaire":{
        "q1":"questionaire1 ",
        "q2":"questionaire2",
        "q3":"questionaire3"
    }
}
```

Comment: html and angular code : https://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/7MhLd/

Comment: Your example works fine. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is recommended.

Comment: not working sir , please help me https://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/7MhLd/

Comment: You can use ng-repeat only to Arrays and not json. What is the data that you want to show, share the complete data in the question

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine. What is the issue exactly ?

Comment: {
    "questionaire":{
        "q1":"questionaire1 ",
        "q2":"questionaire2",
        "q3":"questionaire3"
    }
} this data i want ot show in webpage but it not coming

Comment: @sunithab you can loop through object using ng-repeat.

Comment: @sunithab  `<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
  <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>`

Comment: i copied code and past into my code butt this one also not working https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2345/

Comment: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/7MhLd/2357/) should work

Answer (score 0):

In Your angular Controller,

```
$scope.json_data_sample = {

"questionaire":{
    "q1":"questionaire1 ",
    "q2":"questionaire2",
    "q3":"questionaire3"
}
};
```

In your html view,

```
<div>{{json_data_sample.questionaire.q1}}</div>
<div>{{json_data_sample.questionaire.q2}}</div>
<div>{{json_data_sample.questionaire.q3}}</div>
```

OR

In Html View

```
<div ng-repeat= "json_item in json_data_sample">
  <div>{{json_item.q1}}</div>
   <div>{{json_item.q2}}</div>
    <div>{{json_item.q3}}</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: here inside controller json object is thete but i create seperate json file file name is en_us.json but when loading in controller but brower is not coming

Comment: traied above code still it is not coming and also updated jsfiddle can you check https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2349/

Comment: The fiddle works as expected if you remove the ng-app from the body tag.

Comment: yes i removed but still it is not coming can you show me in jsfiddle

Comment: I said `<body>` tag. It's hidden by default, click on the _HTML_ button.

Comment: u cannot to ng-repeat on a object either it should be a array or array of objetcs

Answer (score 0):

[You Need To clear Body tag

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

to

```
<body>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ij9g.png)